# Does power series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} z^n$ converge on radius?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

The problem is: find radius of convergence and test convergence of series  on boundary:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} z^n,$$

where $z \in \mathbb{C}$. I found that $R= \frac{1}{4}$. Now, we have to test convergence for $|z|=\frac{1}{4}$. I tried to consider the modulus of general term of series.  WolframAlpha shows that  $|\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} z^n| =\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} ( \frac{1}{4})^n \rightarrow 0 $, as $n\rightarrow \infty$, so I cannot conclude that the general term doesn't to $0$ (which would lead to divergence).
My questions are:

1. How can I show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} ( \frac{1}{4})^n  =0?$
2. How to test convergence on the radius?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) may be helpful in your first question.

Comment: 1:[Central_binomial_coefficient#Asymptotic_growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Asymptotic_growth). 2: [Central_binomial_coefficient#Generating_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Generating_function).

Comment: @Feng Thank you! Also, I am wondering how it can be proved that the limit is $0$ without Stirling's approximation?